# How to find out CPU utilization, Memory usage, battery usage and etc. for my application in iOS

Tags: ios

we want display statistics of the application. I have application running. Every min it has to display CPU utilization, Memory utilization and Battery usage of my application. Im able to get overall CPU and memory Utilization. How do we get only for my application. Even I can get battery level but how can i get how much battery it has used by my application.  It should be like Activity monitor how it displays against each process. All these information i have to display in iOS application. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Stop using irrelevant tags. Read the tag descriptions before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is already implemented in Nimbus lib http://latest.docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusOverview.html

You can other use it from the box or search there for ideas and solutions.
[image]

[image]